# How to fit column name in the text width of my document

Tags: header-footer

I'm trying to create a table but the size of the headers does not fit the size of the table.
Can somebody help me with this?
[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{placeins}
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\usepackage{graphicx,booktabs,mhchem,makecell,array}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{multirow}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[H]
    \centering
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}YYYYYYY@{}}
    \toprule
    \multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{\makecell{Mobility\\group}}}& \multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{\makecell{Mobility\\group long}}} & \multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{\makecell{CHL1\\ no sens.}}}& \multicolumn{3}{c}{\textbf{\makecell{Cars}}}&
    %\multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{\makecell{shares\\added}}} & 
    \multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{\makecell{CHL1\\with sens.}}} \\
    \cmidrule{4-6}
    & & & \textbf{0} & \textbf{1} & \textbf{2} & \\
    \midrule
    1 & R1HH1IC1 &   1.94 &  1.64 &  0.27 &  0.03 3 & 0.59 \\
    2 & R1HH1IC2 &   2.94 &  1.56 &  1.03 &  0.34  & 3.10 \\
    3 & R1HH1IC3 &   0.59 &  0.06 &  0.17 &  0.37 & 1.64 \\
    4 & R1HH2IC1 &   2.86 &  2.41 &  0.40 &  0.04 & 0.88 \\
    5 & R1HH2IC2 &   4.33 &  2.31 &  1.52 &  0.50 & 4.57 \\
    6 & R1HH2IC3 &   0.87 &  0.08 &  0.25 &  0.54 & 2.42 \\
    7 & R1HH3IC1 &   7.79 &  6.58 &  1.09 &  0.11 & 2.39 \\
    8 & R1HH3IC2 &  11.80 &  6.29 &  4.15 &  1.36 & 12.47 \\
    9 & R1HH3IC3 &   2.38 &  0.23 &  0.67 &  1.48 & 6.59 \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}
    
    \caption{Caption}
    \label{tab:nn}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please don't post code fragments. Instead put the fragment into a compilable document that people can play with.

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't compile: still missing some packages.

Comment: Hey Alan, I believe now you should be able to compile. Let me know!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Switching from `Y` to `c` columns for the three "cars" columns saves a lot of space. And, since we're continuing to use the `Y` column type for the remaining four columns, don't make life needlessly tedious with `\multirow` and `\makecell` directives with explicit linebreaks; just let LaTeX handle this job for you, with the help of a suitably defined `\mytab` macro; see below for how it's defined.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx,booktabs,amsmath}
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\newcolumntype{P}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{\hsize}}
\newcommand\mytab[1]{\smash[b]{%
   \begin{tabular}[t]{@{} P @{}} #1 \end{tabular}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[ht]
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} YYYcccY @{}}
    \toprule
    \bfseries \mytab{Mobility group} & 
    \bfseries \mytab{Mobility group long} &
    \bfseries \mytab{CHL1 no~sens.} & 
    \multicolumn{3}{c}{\bfseries Cars} & 
    \bfseries \mytab{CHL1 with sens.} \\
    \cmidrule(lr){4-6}
    & & & \textbf{0} & \textbf{1} & \textbf{2}  \\
    \midrule
    1 & R1HH1IC1 &   1.94 &  1.64 &  0.27 &  0.03 & 0.59 \\
    2 & R1HH1IC2 &   2.94 &  1.56 &  1.03 &  0.34 & 3.10 \\
    3 & R1HH1IC3 &   0.59 &  0.06 &  0.17 &  0.37 & 1.64 \\
    4 & R1HH2IC1 &   2.86 &  2.41 &  0.40 &  0.04 & 0.88 \\
    5 & R1HH2IC2 &   4.33 &  2.31 &  1.52 &  0.50 & 4.57 \\
    6 & R1HH2IC3 &   0.87 &  0.08 &  0.25 &  0.54 & 2.42 \\
    7 & R1HH3IC1 &   7.79 &  6.58 &  1.09 &  0.11 & 2.39 \\
    8 & R1HH3IC2 &  11.80 &  6.29 &  4.15 &  1.36 &12.47 \\
    9 & R1HH3IC3 &   2.38 &  0.23 &  0.67 &  1.48 & 6.59 \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}
    \caption{Caption} \label{tab:nn}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Works perfectly! Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Master_student_H2 If you like any of the answers for your questions (this one and previous) and it was helpful, please consider [upvoting](http://tex.stackexchange.com/privileges/vote-up) (by clicking on the arrows next to the score) and/or marking it as the [accepted answer](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852) (by clicking on the checkmark ✓) `:)`